# Calculate count based on multiple groups of 7 number range in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, count, grouping

Can someone please help me out, I stuck here.

**Given**

```
AMOUNT  CUSTOMER_NUMBER GROUPID SEQF
1000+   5555            51      2       
1000+   5555            52      3
1000+   5555            55      4   
1000+   5555            56      4   
1000+   5555            57      4       
1000+   5555            58      2   
1000+   5555            59      4   
1000+   5555            61      2
2000+   6666            55      2
.
.   
.
.
```

By considering AMOUNT and CUSTOMER_NUMBER columns, here creating group within 7 GROUPID Numbers

**For e.g.** 
1st Group for 5555 CUSTOMER_NUMBER -> (51 to 57 GROUP ID), 2nd Group for 5555 CUSTOMER_NUMBER (58 to 61 GROUP ID), 3rd Group for 6666 CUSTOMER_NUMBER (55 GROUP ID)

**Needed:**

IF SEQF >=2 in 1st Group in any of the GROUPID from 51 to 57 then consider COUNT(SEQF) = 1

IF SEQF >=2 in 2nd Group in any of the GROUPID from 58 to 61  then consider COUNT(SEQF) = 1

so total here

```
AMOUNT  CUSTOMER_NUMBER COUNT(SEQF)
1000+       5555                2
```

IF SEQF >=2 in 3rd Group in any of the GROUPID from 55 then consider COUNT(SEQF) = 1

```
AMOUNT  CUSTOMER_NUMBER COUNT(SEQF)
2000+       6666                1
```

**Desired Output**

```
AMOUNT  CUSTOMER_NUMBER COUNT(SEQF)
1000+       5555                2
2000+       6666                1
```

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL? You tagged both, maybe by accident? If you use MySQL, what version do you use?

Comment: Are the groups of `groupid` fixed in anyway, e.g. the first group is always 51 to 57? Or just packs of 7 in the order of the `groupid`? If so, can there be gaps and what to do if there are any gaps -- take 7 no matter the gap or not?

Comment: Yes, It's Oracle. I tagged mysql by mistake. It's packs of 7 in the order of the groupid. Also, we have to consider gap to take 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the other answers solve the problem where there are gaps between groups (they just assume groups are contiguous). This will skip gaps and put the `groupid` into ranges of 7.

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
create table data(amount, customer_number, groupid, seqf) as (
    select '1000+', 5555, 51, 2 from dual union all
    select '1000+', 5555, 52, 3 from dual union all
    select '1000+', 5555, 55, 4 from dual union all
    select '1000+', 5555, 56, 4 from dual union all
    select '1000+', 5555, 57, 4 from dual union all
    select '1000+', 5555, 60, 2 from dual union all
    select '1000+', 5555, 61, 4 from dual union all
    select '1000+', 5555, 65, 2 from dual union all
    select '1000+', 5555, 69, 2 from dual union all
    select '2000+', 6666, 55, 2 from dual );
```

**Query 1**:

This finds the groups:

```sql
SELECT amount,
       customer_number,
       groupid,
       groupid + 6 AS max_groupid
FROM   (
  SELECT d.*,
         MIN( groupid )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY amount, customer_number )
           AS min_groupid,
         MIN( groupid )
           OVER (
             PARTITION BY amount, customer_number
             ORDER BY groupid
             RANGE BETWEEN 7 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
           )
           AS next_groupid
  FROM   data d
)
START WITH groupid = min_groupid
CONNECT BY PRIOR amount          = amount
AND        PRIOR customer_number = customer_number
AND        PRIOR next_groupid    = groupid
```

which outputs:

> ```
> AMOUNT | CUSTOMER_NUMBER | GROUPID | MAX_GROUPID
> :----- | --------------: | ------: | ----------:
> 1000+  |            5555 |      51 |          57
> 1000+  |            5555 |      60 |          66
> 1000+  |            5555 |      69 |          75
> 2000+  |            6666 |      55 |          61
> ```

**Query 2**:

This counts the groups:

```sql
SELECT amount,
       customer_number,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   (
  SELECT d.*,
         MIN( groupid )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY amount, customer_number )
           AS min_groupid,
         MIN( groupid )
           OVER (
             PARTITION BY amount, customer_number
             ORDER BY groupid
             RANGE BETWEEN 7 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
           )
           AS next_groupid
  FROM   data d
)
START WITH groupid = min_groupid
CONNECT BY PRIOR amount          = amount
AND        PRIOR customer_number = customer_number
AND        PRIOR next_groupid    = groupid
GROUP BY amount, customer_number
```

which outputs:

> ```
> AMOUNT | CUSTOMER_NUMBER | COUNT(*)
> :----- | --------------: | -------:
> 1000+  |            5555 |        3
> 2000+  |            6666 |        1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c2542c6143ac0b70336d748b26255b9d)*

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to group 7 records and find some details then again group by customer and amount to get final result.

One way to do this is:

```
Select amount, customer_number, sum(seqf) as seqf 
from
  (Select amount, customer_number, 
          case when sum(case when seqf>= 2 then 1 end) >= 1 then 1 end as seqf 
     from
       (Select t.*, 
               Row_number() over(partition by amount, customer_number order by groupid) as rn
          From your_table t)
        Group by amount, customer_number, trunc((rn-1)/7))
Group by amount, customer_number;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to find 7 GROUPID ranges at first, for instance use this hierarchical query:

```
with ranges(amt, cn, g1, g2, mxg) as (
  select amount, customer_number, min(groupid), min(groupid) + 6, max(groupid)
    from data group by amount, customer_number union all
  select amt, cn, g1 + 7, g2 + 7, mxg from ranges where g1 + 7 <= mxg)
select amt, cn, g1, g2, mxg from ranges
```

Which gives us lower and upper limit of each range (G1, G2):

```
AMT           CN         G1         G2 
----- ---------- ---------- ---------- 
1000+       5555         51         57 
1000+       5555         58         64 
2000+       6666         55         61
```

Now we can join these ranges with your data, count conditionally and sum counts:

```
with ranges(amt, cn, g1, g2, mxg) as (
    select amount, customer_number, min(groupid), min(groupid) + 6, max(groupid)
      from data group by amount, customer_number union all
    select amt, cn, g1 + 7, g2 + 7, mxg from ranges where g1 + 7 <= mxg)
select amt, cn, sum(cs) cnt
  from (
    select amt, cn, g1, g2, case when max(seqf) >= 2 then 1 end cs
      from ranges
      join data on amt = amount and cn = customer_number 
               and groupid between g1 and g2
      group by amt, cn, g1, g2)
  group by amt, cn
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=082386decddba5d0333faff85fad6150)</sup>**

I used `max(seqf)` because your words *IF SEQF >=2 in 1st Group in any of the GROUPID* suggest this. If you want first value in that group for instance, use `min ... keep dense rank first`.

---

You can also substract groupid and minimum groupid for each (amount, customer_number), divide by 7, use floor and this will create groups, this will be faster:

```
select amount, customer_number, sum(seqf)
  from (
    select amount, customer_number, case when max(seqf) >= 2 then 1 end seqf
      from (
        select data.*, 
               floor((groupid - min(groupid) over (partition by amount, customer_number))/7) gid
          from data)
      group by amount, customer_number, gid)
  group by amount, customer_number
```